# How to judge a notification whether can be sent to Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

The apple doc said `"When one of your app’s local or remote notification arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on Apple Watch"`

And I want to know how can I display that notification on Apple Watch only? how can I display that notification on iPhone only? Apple support any property ?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to specify that a push notification should only be sent to the Apple Watch, and not to the iPhone.

If this is a capability you'd like to have, you should file an enhancement request at https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Hi,Dave. If I have an iPhone and a paired iWatch , the distance is very near. Is there any situations the notification only received by iPhone , but not push to iWatch?